# Can Facebook Page and third party website share Likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my head around this FB API thing and I wonder if it is possible to share likes between FB page and a website.

For example: I have a website example.com that has a like social plug-in button on it, I also have a FB page(as recommended by FB, not sure why I need one) for example.com.
What happens when the user clicks on like? Is it possible to interconnect these entities so that the likes don't get scattered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Facebook like-button to a [**like-box**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) containing the id of your page.

An example of this would be:

```
<div 
    class="fb-like-box" 
    data-href="http://www.facebook.com/example.comFB" data-width="300" 
    data-height="300" data-show-faces="true" 
    data-stream="true" data-header="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea, but this like box doesn't fit the website layout. Even with the minimum settings.

Comment: I have found out that I can set the FB page url in the like button, so I will mark your answer as accepted.